# All href in html produces 404 error when using APS.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I just migrated all my html code to APS.NET Core, but all links to other pages failed and give 404 error, for instance this bookmark links to the file `Companies.cshtml` which is in the same View/Home folder.

```
<div>
     <a href="Companies.cshtml#google-i">foo</a>
</div>
```

I tried to add folders to the workspace with browser inspection but no avail.
I also tried add `~/` to the path, does not work.
I've noticed that the localhost cannot find the file `Companies.cshtml` in a virtual file system(?) and thus may be the reason that produces the error. How may I bypass the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot link to a view. You need an action that loads that view, and then you link to the route that directs to that action.Read [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.

For example:

You can create an Companies action in HomeController :

```
public IActionResult Companies()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

then use

```
<div>
 <a href="/Home/Companies#google-i">foo</a>
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, it helps a lot and precisely solve the problem.